# Is it possible to set up a 'no re-entry' rule for a triggered automation in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, entry-criteria

In Journey Builder you can set the contact entry rule 'No re-entry'.  Is there a way to set up something similar with a non-journey builder automation?

I have an automation running hourly.  I'd like to set the update method on my query to 'update', have new records added to my data extension, and then have the automated email only deploy to records newly added to the data extension (those who haven't been sent the email).

Is this possible and if so is there a setting I am missing or can this be done in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set such a rule in an Automation that is sending email  but here is a workaround -

Use a flag in your Data Extension which tells if its an updated record (eligible to receive email)

Then in your email, use AMPScript to fail the send for any subscriber which doesn't have the flag set

Comment: I'm not sure if I quit understand.  Wouldn't this just keep sending email to the same records each time the automation is run?  How would I remove the 'email eligible' flag once the email is sent?

Comment: That you need to handle through query

Comment: you could also put an upsert inside the email to update the field to remove the eligible flag at send time.